# Calling an SQL Server stored procedure with params in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

this is my 1st post here and as a beginner in PHP so please tread lightly!!

I am using PHP 5.3 and SQL Server 2012 express

My problem is executing an SQL server stored procedure from PHP that has parameters where the value of the parameter comes from a $_POST variable from an HTML form.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
    <?php
    require_once("../includes/initialize.php");
    //
    global $database;


    $username = "someone";
    $params = array($username); 
    $conn = $database->connection;

    $admin_set = sqlsrv_query($conn, "{call find_admin_by_username_p}", $params); 
    if($admin = $database->fetch_array($admin_set)) {
        var_dump($admin);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    //
    /* THIS WORKS
    global $database;

    $admin_set = $database->query("{call find_admin_by_username}");
    if($admin = $database->fetch_array($admin_set)) {
        var_dump($admin);
      } else {
        return null;
    }
    */
    ?>
```

The code for the stored procedure is:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[find_admin_by_username_p]
@username nvarchar(55)
    AS
    BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dbo.users
WHERE username = @username
    END
```

For the commented "THIS WORKS" section the procedure find_admin_by_username works as this doesn't contain any parameters. However I want to have the @username as a variable that is provided by a $_POST form field.

My main reason for doing this is to help prevent SQL injection, also I would be escaping the values once connected to the form.

This is a link to a lot of the info I have looked at so far

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection.aspx

I have also searched through many other blogs but don't seem to be able to find anything that works.

Please help!

Comment: Hi folks I have now solved this, I needed to add ( ?) after the call procedure so:

Comment: $admin_set = sqlsrv_query($conn, "{call find_admin_by_username_p( ?)}", $params);

Comment: You can answer your own question, below